# Esent crashes with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, esent, edb

I've been using ESENT for my projects quite extensively and I really love how easy and fast it works. And stable too!!

But I have a HUGE problem with **Windows 8**!!! Regardless of how I link to the esent.dll (dynamically or statically) whenever I call something other than JetSetSystemParameter, the dll is crashing, takig my app along down the cliff.

The event viewer tells me the following:
Exception Code: 0xc0000090
Error Offset: 0x0003090e
esent ver: 6.2.8400.0

Did anybody encounter similar problems with Windows 8?

Comment: Oh, I hope Laurion Burchall is still around to help me on this one!!!

Comment: My initial (random) guess is a calling convention problem. Do you have a callstack that you can share?

Comment: Have you ever used windbg|cdb|ntds? If you could run it in one of those debuggers, then grab a crash dump (with `.dump /ma .\DumpOfYourProcess.dm_`), that would be easiest for me to debug ... send to brettsh -at- micrsoft . [I'm sure you can guess the TLD]. Unless there is a way to upload a dump to stackoverflow. I am assuming this code worked in Win7? Oh and just curious are you using it in a Metro / WinRT / App environment, or just regularly? And if you've figured it out, I'd be curious to know what fixed it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Laurion, Brett, unfortunately it still doesn't work for me. There not much happening in the callstack. I actually created a tiny test program, that simply sets the database pagesize and the tries to create an instance. Basically it's this: JetSetSystemParameter and then JetCreateInstance. I also tried JetCreateInstance2, with the same crashing results.


I am using Delphi for this project, so it's not Metro nor WinRT.

Comment: I am sure you are right about a calling convention problem, but I tried every possible (?) way to call the method and pass the JET_INSTANCE pointer. The only time it doesn't crash is when I pass NULL instead of a pointer. In that case I get a JET_errInvalidParameter, which is what I expected. My code worked just perfectly so far with Windows XP/Vista/7!!